# How to include Libraray of ALCameraViewController in Swift

Tags: swift

I'd like to include ALCameraViewController from

https://github.com/AlexLittlejohn/ALCameraViewController

to have a cropping VC.
After importing with CocoaPods, I pasted the code like the description says:

```
let croppingEnabled = true
let cameraViewController = CameraViewController(croppingEnabled: croppingEnabled) { [weak self] image, asset in
    // Do something with your image here.
    // If cropping is enabled this image will be the cropped version

    self?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

presentViewController(cameraViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

- But the problem is, that "CameraViewController" is not be found.
- I think I need to "import ALCameraViewController" but the word "ALCameraViewController" is not accepted to import.

I dont know how to move on? Anybody an idea to help with this question?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you using the .xcworkspace project?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install with CocoaPods?

Yes->

`import ALCameraViewController` in your `UIViewController` should work. Don't forget to open the `.xcworkspace` file.

No-> (downloaded from `gitHub` and manually added the files)

You don't need to import. Just use the example that the project provide.

Comment: Thank you very much . I did the same yesterday. But now after rebooting the Mac and do it again it was working. Weird but big thanks!